# Загрузка фотографий в папку сайта

Tags: php

Не могу разобраться как загрузить фотографию и вывести ее. Только пожалуйста не кричите что я что-то не туда кидаю, я только разбираюсь :). Новичок в php. Суть вот в чем, делаю блок новостей в котором, каждая новость должна иметь фото. Больше картинок, чтобы вы понимали суть. Немогу нигде найти как хоть примерно это делается [image: мои новости] Как исправить загрузку этих фото в админ меню? При загрузке фотографии и при создании новости фото должно отправляться в папку /assets/img/avatar [image: мой дизайн админ меню] Загрузку данных делаю используя контролеры для шаблонов.
Контролер для создания (кусочек кода):

```
        $this->load->model('news');
    
    if($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $errorPOST = $this->validatePOST();
        if(!$errorPOST) {
            $name = @$this->request->post['name'];
            $text = @$this->request->post['text'];
            
            $userid = $this->user->getId();
            
            $newsData = array(
                'user_id'           => $userid,
                'news_title'        => $name,
                'news_text'         => $text,
                'news_image'        => $imagee,
            );
            $newsid = $this->newsModel->createNews($newsData);

            
            $this->data['status'] = "success";
            $this->data['success'] = "Вы успешно создали новость!";
            $this->data['id'] = $newsid;
        } else {
            $this->data['status'] = "error";
```

Вид создания новости:

```
                <form action="#" id="createForm" method="POST">
            <fieldset>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="message">Заголовок</label>
                    <textarea placeholder="Введите заголовок для новости" class="form-control" rows="1" name="name" id="name"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="message">Сообщение</label>
                    <textarea placeholder="Введите свое сообщение" class="form-control" rows="5" name="text" id="text"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Изображение</label>
                    <form form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="imagee" action="/ajax.php/?mod=avatars">
                        <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="99d53829a397fdd01984e46e2c28d69f"><br>
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <div class="form-group" style="overflow:hidden;">
                                <div class="pull-left" style="margin-right:20px;"><img height="50px" class="img-circle" width="50px" src="/assets/img/avatar/'.$user['img'].'" /></div>
                                <div class="pull-left">
                                    <p for="fieldavatar">Выберите изображение</p>
                                    <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="userfile" id="fieldavatar">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-footer">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Создать"><span id="imagee" class="pull-right"></span> 
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        </form>
```

И на конец сам вывод новостей index.html

```
                    <section class="feed-item">
                        <div class="icon pull-left">
                            <i class="fa fa-newspaper-o">&nbsp;</i>
                        </div>
                        <img src="/assets/img/avatar/'.$imagee['imagee'].'" width="65px" height="65px" class="img-circle pull-right">
      
                        <?php echo $item['news_image'] ?>
                        <div class="feed-item-body">
                            <div class="text"><b><?php echo $item['news_title'] ?></b><br>              <?php echo $item['news_text'] ?></div>
                            <div class="time pull-right"> <?php echo date("d.m", strtotime($item['news_date_add'])) ?>.<?php echo date("Y", strtotime($item['news_date_add'])) ?></span></div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                    </section>
```

Вид базы данных: [image: бд]